# IllegalArgumentException:TypeMismatch when trying to mock JOptionPane

Tags: swing, unit-testing, junit, mocking, joptionpane

Why do I get an `IllegalArgumentException:TypeMismatch` here?

```
@PrepareForTest({ JOptionPane.class })
...        
PowerMockito.mockStatic(JOptionPane.class)
PowerMockito.doNothing().when(JOptionPane.class, "showMessageDialog", Component.class, Object.class);
```

Thanks for your advice!